# Could not load project, Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

I have resolved the merge issues, tried pod install, But its throwing below error :

> CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 6255. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.

How to resolve the issue. Not able to find the issue.
Tried resetting the brach and again merging it. But yields the same result

Comment: Try to open the plist with Other editor, then find the line 6225. You will work it out.

Comment: How to resolve which is causing this issue?

Comment: @SeanChense Ok will try this

Comment: @SeanChense which plist?

Comment: Looks like there is an error in Localizable.strings

Comment: But not using Localizable.strings

Comment: So, that is the project plist.

Comment: No plist is having 6225 line. :(

Comment: looked into project plist . but it looks fine

Comment: @SeanChense: its the end of the line. If i add ** } ** , pod install error changes

Comment: It seems missing semicolon in dictionary